# JavaScript class creation with private members

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm working on a utility to create classes in javascript.
And it works, the problem is how to define private attributes.

This is the code

```
var OO = {

    Class:function(){

        var len = arguments.length;
        var data = arguments[len-1];



        var Klass;
        if (data.constructor === Object){
            Klass = function (){};

        } else {
            Klass = data.constructor;
            delete data.constructor;                
        }



        OO.extend(Klass.prototype,data); //Classic Extend Method


        return Klass;


    },
//Simple extend method, just what I need in this case
    extend: function(target, source){
            var prop;
            for (prop in source)
                target[prop] = source [prop];

    }
}
```

This is how it works

```
// first create a class
var person = OO.Class ({
constructor: function (name, age) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
},

name:'',
age:'',

getName: function () {
return this.name;
},

getAge: function () {
return this.age;
}

});
```

And here is the instance

```
var one = new Person ('josh', 22);
```

And the problem:

```
one.age / / returns 22
one.name / / returns josh
```

**What I need is that these properties can only be accessed by methods like getName () and getAge ()**

**EDIT1**: Added Extend Function

Comment: You barely can do that using your current solution.

Comment: Why do some people insist on coding JavaScript classically?

Comment: You may be interested in Douglas Crockford's [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) article.

Comment: @RobG yeaph, thanks for the link...

Comment: @AlienWebguy this aged well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1:**

Here it the working prototype.  It works except for

1.)  Passing in construction values to private members.

```
 Dummy values do work however.
```

Test out the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UWRHP/11/

Comment: the extend implementation is posted! I want all the attributes private, so the user can't acces it directly via instance.attrib, he must define getters and setters. Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but is a little bit hard to get online from here (I'm from the Caribbean). In response to your question, I've edited the original post since that implementation does not exist (by now). It's a future idea to try to extend from parent classes.

Comment: like I say before, it's hard to get online from here, so one more time apologize me, please write your implementation and the vote is for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Josh - Here is way to create privacy I believe ( different approach al l together ).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491005/how-to-create-privacy-with-the-use-of-bind

Answer (score 1):

The closure is created by the constructor params, so this is all you need to do (edited AlienWebguy's code):

```
var Person = function(name, age){

    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    };

    this.getAge = function() {
        return age;
    };

};

var john = new Person('johnathan', 33);

document.writeln(john.name);        // undefined
document.writeln(john.age);         // undefined
document.writeln(john.getName());   // johnathan
document.writeln(john.getAge());    // 33
```

Comment: +1 I deleted my answer, this one is much better if the OP doesn't want any setters.

Comment: I'm curious why almost every answer here has downvotes! Apparently JavaScript encapsulation is something people feel very strongly about.

Answer (score -1):

Any variable which is part of the object's interface (ie `this.x` and `this.y`) will be public. You will not be able to force access external access to those variables to go via the getters.

So, as long as you have code like this:

```
getAge: function () {
    return this.age;
}
```

... you cannot prevent this:

```
var one = new Person ('josh', 22);
console.log(one.age);
```

Check out Douglas Crockford's article [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: Based on my code... any idea of how to force attributes to be privates and only accesible via getters ?

Comment: Maybe it's too much to ask, but could you at least guide me, no matter what I have to redefine what I've done

Comment: @Jash Gazman - Have you taken a look at my other answer, or Stylez's more concise but similar answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to not over complicate things (and completely ditch what you've done so far) as @AlienWebguy suggests, you don't even need the `.io` member - which in the end is exposed just as much as the `.name` and `.age` properties were:

```
john.io.set('name', 'Johnny'); // still exposed!
```

In the end, the `.io` object is just as exposed as the `.name` and `.age` properties, so it's a complicated solution which doesn't make any progress on encapsulation nor information hiding. (sorry, @AlienWebguy, that's just the way I feel)

If you're trying to use a classical inheritance paradigm and ditching conventional JavaScript OOP entirely, then ditch the conventional functions-as-constructors paradigm and forget about using the `this` reference in your constructors:

```
// first create a constructor
var Person = function(arg0, arg1) {

    var that = {};

    // private variables

    var age = arg0;
    var name = arg1;

    // public methods

    that.getName = function() {
        return name;
    };

    that.getAge = function() {
        return age;
    };

    that.setAge = function(a) {
        age = a;
    };

    return that;

};

var john = new Person('johnathan', 33);

console.log(john.name);        // undefined
console.log(john.getName());   // 'johnathan'
console.log(john.age);        // undefined
console.log(john.getAge());   // 33
john.setAge(28);
console.log(john.getAge());   // 28
john.setName("Richard");      // Error - setName is not a function
```

This is an example of Douglas Crockford's [Parasitic Inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)... but without the "inheritance" part. The point is, the instance variables `age` and `name` are private, but remain in scope because of JavaScript's functional variable scoping, so the object's methods can still manipulate them.

You'll also notice that the `name` variable has no setter, so this technique legitimately will allow you to control access to the `name` variable - there is no hidden `this.name` nor `this.io` which will allow the variable to be manipulated; it is entirely private.

Comment: Creating local vars `age` and `name` is redundant and confusing.

Comment: @Stylez - Redundant? What is repeated?

Comment: The arguments being passed are already local to that scope. You renamed them `arg0` and `arg1` and reassigned them for no reason. See my code for clarification.